# PHP dataValidation error

Tags: php, function, validation

In my form am validating user input so i made `dataValidation` and added `htmlspecialchars()`

```
      <?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$post_cat = dataValidation("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

function dataValidation($cleandata) {
    $data = trim($cleandata);
    $data = stripslashes($cleandata);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($cleandata);
    return $cleandata;
}

echo $post_cat;
```

When i echo i get **output** like this `<a href='test'>Test</a>`

**But actually when using** `htmlspecialchars()`

**Output should be like this :**

`&lt;a href='test'&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;`

But in my case `dataValidation` function is not working

Comment: you aren't using any of your other arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return $cleandata;
```

Should be

```
return $data;
```

Also you're throwing away intermediate values of `$data`. You probably don't want that.

---

Not really part of the answer, but I would recommend you use an IDE with code analysis. Code analysis would be able to tell you that `$data` isn't getting used after *each* assignment. This would allow you to catch this bug early.

Comment: am using net beans how do i check in that??

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment basically a really fancy text editor geared for writing code. I personally use PHPStorm which is really great but not free. Eclipse is equally great _and_ free.

Comment: I think NetBeans does it automatically. Make sure it detects your language correctly (PHP). Some editors get a little confused when you mix PHP, HTML, CSS and JavaScript in one file.

Comment: If you're worried about XSS you don't need `stripslashes`, `htmlspecialchars` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

i think it should be like this

```
   function dataValidation($cleandata) {
     $data = trim($cleandata);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
   }
```